# need to wait for soapClient result

Tags: node.js, node-soap

Hi All this is my first qestion on stackoverflow.
I wrote a fuction that expect result from soapClient call in nodejs, but it dont wait for the call return, and the return value is empty.

I try several modification of the code but i cant get the expected result.
I expect some output but it is empty.

Note URLS are fictitious!!

Thanks somebody can help me!!

```
import * as soap from "soap";

function getTokens(service: string): String {

    let Auth = "";

    function Call(err: any, client: soap.Client) {

        client.loginCms({ in0: service }, function (
            err: any,
            result: any,
            _rawResponse: string, 
            _soapHeader: any,
            _rawRequest: string
        ) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
             } else {
                Auth = result.loginCmsReturn;
             }
         });
    }

    soap.createClient("wsdl_url", {
        disableCache: true,
        envelopeKey: "env"
    }, Call, "endpoint_url");

    // here return an empty value
    return Auth;
};

const Auth = getTokens("service");
console.log(Auth); // empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use promises like in [this example](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#soapcreateclienturl-options-callback---create-a-new-soap-client-from-a-wsdl-url-also-supports-a-local-filesystem-path) taken from the `soap` package documentation.

The code you have the is not asynchronic, so it doesn't wait for the operation to be completed.

It should look something like this

```
import * as soap from "soap";

function getTokens(service: string): Promise<string> {

    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {

        function Call(err: any, client: soap.Client) {

            client.loginCms({ in0: service }, function (
                err: any,
                result: any,
                _rawResponse: string, 
                _soapHeader: any,
                _rawRequest: string
            ) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    reject(err)
                 } else {
                    Auth = result.loginCmsReturn;
                    resolve(Auth);
                 }
             });
        }

        soap.createClient("wsdl_url", {
            disableCache: true,
            envelopeKey: "env"
        }, Call, "endpoint_url");

    });
};

getTokens("service").then((Auth) => {
    console.log(Auth);
});
```

Also note that:

- I follow your variable names, **but** identifiers with Capital letter at the beginning should be used for constructors or class names.
- Also check your TypeScript/JavaScript/EcmaScript version to see if arrow functions (like in my example) are compatible. If not you can convert then to normal anonymous functions.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, yes i can get the value inside the callback function "Call". But i need the value outside of "Call" as it can return it from the container function "getTokens".

Comment: Just added an example modifying your code. Hope that helps.
Also, if you can use asyn/await syntax in your code, you can change the last part to: `const Auth = await getTokens("service");`. That would wait for the result and leave it in `Auth`, but it is equivalent, just syntax-sugar.

Comment: Thank Daniel, I try with promises an so on, but I think some buggy behavior whit promises inside promises. The code is in TypeScript. I not discard the buggy is my brain :-) last await dont work

Comment: Oh, one more comment about the `await`. They must be inside an `async` function. Forgot to tell you in my prev answer. You can just create an async function as a IIFE.